# Meaning of "the" general fiber in the paper "La conjecture de Weil : I"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, weil-conjectures

In section 4.1, chapter 4 of Pierre Deligne's paper *La conjecture de Weil : I* ([french version](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1974__43__273_0), [translation to English](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.10810)) he states:

Let $X$ be a non singular analytic space and purely of dimension $n+1$. Let $D=\{z: |z|< 1 \}$ the unitary  disc and $D^*=D-\{0\}$, and let $f: X\rightarrow D$ a morphism of analytic spaces such that:

- $f$ is proper
- $f$ is smooth outside of a point $x$ of the special fiber $X_0=f^{-1}(0)$.
- In $x$, $f$ has a non-degenerate quadratic point.

Let $t\neq 0$ in $D$ and $X_t=f^{-1}(t)$ "the" general fiber...

I think he use the word: "the" general fiber (*«la» fibre générale*, in the original),  for any fiber different from $X_0$, but I am not sure maybe this phrase has a deeper meaning. Maybe someone has read this book and can clarify this to me :).

Comment: You've interpreted the text correctly! Deligne has put "the" in scare quotes because the choice of non-zero t is irrelevant; the point is that different t yield homeomorphic (though not algebraically isomorphic) spaces, so from the PoV of topology the choice of t doesn't matter. (Note that these fibers are not canonically homotopy-equivalent, and indeed the failure of canonicity is measured by the monodromy operator...)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @DanielLitt! :D...Can you tell me what does he mean by "cycles singuliers" (see  item $\beta$)? I know what a cycle is, but I did not hear about singular cycles.

Comment: I think this just means "singular homology/cohomology" (i.e. Deligne is thinking of an element of singular homology as being represented by a "singular cycle").

Comment: Ohhh I understand. Thank you @DanielLitt ! on the other hand, I think that with this data (for example: $X$ has dimension $n+1$, $D$ is the unitary disk, ...) Deligne assumes that  all the fibers has dimension $n$. If so, why it should be obvious?

Comment: Why should what be obvious?

Comment: That all the fibers has dimension $n$.

Comment: If $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is dominant,  then for a generic $Q\in Y$ the dimension of the fiber $f^{-1}(Q)=\dim X-\dim Y$. In your case $Y$ is like the spectrum of a DVR, I think.

Comment: If you want to be more canonical, you can replace the fiber $X_t$ with the (homotopy equivalent) base change of $X\to D$ to “the” universal cover of $D^*$.

Comment: Dear @FZaldivar I think I understand thank you!!!

Comment: Dear @PiotrAchinger can you give a more detailed explanation? :D

Comment: Dear @David Roberts thank you  for editing the question!